# How to add spaces to string in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a string `"AB0123456789"` and the output I would like to have is: `"AB01 2345 6789"` ... I want to add a space after every fourth character. How can I do this?

```
Main> addSpace "AB0123456789"
"AB01 2345 6789"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient:

```
addSpace xs = if length xs <= 4
              then xs
              else take 4 xs ++ " " ++ addSpace (drop 4 xs)
```

Demo in ghci:

```
ghci > addSpace "AB0123456789"
"AB01 2345 6789"
```

Answer (score 14):

With [`Data.List.intercalate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3aintercalate) and [`Data.List.Split.chunksOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v%3achunksOf) this is easy:

```
import Data.List.Split

addSpace :: String -> String
addSpace = intercalate " " . chunksOf 4
```

Answer (score 3):

I would think pattern matching would make this easiest:

```
addSpaces :: String -> String
addSpaces xs@(_:_:_:_:[]) = xs
addSpaces    (a:b:c:d:xs) = a:b:c:d:' ':addSpaces xs
addSpaces xs              = xs
```

You have to include the first case so you don't potentially get a space at the end, but it's pretty straightforward.  This isn't extensible, though, you wouldn't be able to use a function like this to dynamically choose how many characters you want to skip before inserting a space (such as in @cdk's answer)

Comment: If you do not care about readability, you can pattern match on `(a:b:c:d:xs@(_:_))` and remove the first case, because the third one will provide the same result. This is hardly an improvement, though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `splitAt`. Heres a function that adds space after every nth character.

```
spaceN :: Int -> String -> String
spaceN n = init . go
    where go [] = []
          go xs = let (as, bs) = splitAt n xs in as ++ (' ' : go bs)
```

for your specific case:

```
λ. spaceN 4 "AB0123456789"
"AB01 2345 6789"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
window i = unfoldr (\l -> if null l then Nothing else Just (splitAt i l))

addSpace :: String -> String
addSpace = intercalate " " . window 4
```